# Grunt sass task returning ENOENT error unless paths are absolute

Tags: sass, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-sass, enoent

Seem to be getting an issue with my grunt sass task requiring absolute paths. Not sure what change has caused this.

[image: grunt task]

[image]

The issue however seems to be resolved when you I used absolute paths within the Grunt task. The paths are correct as they work across the team.

**Versions:**

Sass - 3.4.21 (Selective Steve)

Node - v4.2.4

Ruby - ruby 1.9.3p551 (2014-11-13) [i386-mingw32]

Grunt - grunt-cli v1.2.0, grunt v0.4.5

These versions are also consistent within the team. However I seem to be the only one affected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: had to remove the value set for **AutoRun** within **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor**